# Chef-server 12.1.0 backup and restore gives me 401

Tags: chef-infra, backup, http-status-code-401

I have a chef server with opscode-manage and I would like to backup everything (config, db etc..) for the restore on an a new server

I have backed-up and gunziped

> - the entire postresql (dump)
> - /etc/opscode
> - /var/opt/opscode

On the new server I have extracted and rsync -a everthing and done a reconfigure.

I checked in the DB and all the orgs and users are there.

Chef manage UI shows UP but I get 401 when I try to login. When I try (to test) to reset the password the password page after clicking submit give me a 401 page

Can someone help debug this ? Which log is going to be helpful here ? postres, ngix and rabbitmq are all without errors

The only error I see it's this for example when I try to signup an account and use the email checker 
(/var/log/opscode-manage/opscode-manage-webapp/current)

```
2018-03-20_17:50:11.41996 Started GET "/signup/validity/email?value=dasdasd%40dsadsa.co" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-20 17:50:11 +0000
2018-03-20_17:50:11.42245 Processing by SessionsController#validate_signup as JSON
2018-03-20_17:50:11.42249   Parameters: {"value"=>"dasdasd@dsadsa.co", "type"=>"email"}
2018-03-20_17:50:11.45565 HTTP Request Returned 401 Unauthorized: error
2018-03-20_17:50:11.45619 401 "Unauthorized"
```

Comment: Are you saying you did that yourself or did you use the normal backup and restore tools? Also yes we do notice when you cross-post here and the mailing list and no it does not make us happy or more likely to help you.

Comment: Since I have chef-server 12.1.0 the backup tool was not yet included. However I just saw there is a knife-ec-backup gem included so I will try this now